# fopen() always return NULL on iOS device

Tags: ios, macos, fopen, ipados

File exists in iOS bundle directory. `fopen()` always return `NULL` on iOS device, but OK on iOS sumulator, codes as below:

```
NSString *path = [NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"yuv420p_640x360" ofType:@"yuv"];
BOOL exists = [NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:path];
NSLog(@"%d", exists); //prints "1"
const char *path2 = [path UTF8String];
FILE *fp = fopen(path2, "rb+"); //fp is NULL
```

Environment: macOS 12.0.1, M1 MacBook Pro, iPadOS 15.0

Comment: The iOS execution environment is sandboxed, and you can not open a file in the bundle with "writing" mode, since the files in the bundle can not be modified (try with just "r" for the mode).

Comment: @ChristosKoninis Yeah, finally I just change "rb+" to "rb" and run OK. thanks

Comment: Since it helped I am moving my comment to an full answer for better visibility in case some one has the same problem to easily find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS execution environment is sandboxed, and you can not open a file in the bundle with "writing" mode, since the files in the bundle can not be modified (try with just "r" for the mode).

Comment: @Smeegol If you find my solution useful please accept it so that others can be helped if they face the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open any file in iOS. Apps are **sandboxed** in iOS i.e. An app can access only its directory and cannot access(read/write) any file outside its directory.